# Lookup type within object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to introduce a lookup type within an object. Let's say my object looks like

```
class PersonList {
  persons = {
    john: 'description of john',
    bob: 'description of bob'
  }
}
```

I'd like to have a getter to get a person from `persons` but without specifying the the `persons` object.

The `getProperty` from the docs

```
function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) {
  return obj[key];  // Inferred type is T[K]
}
```

Wants to have an `obj` which I want to get rid of in my getter. I've tried proxying the getter, but that didn't work out:

```
class PersonList {
  persons = {
    john: 'description of john',
    bob: 'description of bob'
  };

  getPerson(name) {
    return this.getProperty(this.persons, name);
  }

  private getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K) {
    return obj[key];  // Inferred type is T[K]
  }
}
```

This sadly doesn't throw an error when trying to do something like `personList.getPerson('someonenotincluded');` - and additionally autocomplete doesn't work either.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Answering this one? Don't want to steal it 

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - Your answer would probably be better. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder actually in this case since the object props are all of the same type my answer was needlessly complicated, yours is better :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - *(Makes note in diary... ;-) )*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you're totally right, I meant `persons` to be a value, NOT a type. Completely missed that, really sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd take that inline type and name it (but keep reading, you don't *have* to):

```
interface Persons {
  john: string;
  bob: string;
}
```

Then you can use `keyof Persons` as the parameter type in `getPerson`:

```
class PersonList {
  persons: Persons = {
    john: 'description of john',
    bob: 'description of bob'
  };

  getPerson(name: keyof Persons) {
    return this.persons[name];
  }
}
```

So then if `pl` is a `PersonList`:

```
console.log(pl.getPerson('john')); // Works
console.log(pl.getPerson('someonenotincluded')); // Error
```

[Live on the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsQeQbwChlkArLACxAC5kMwpQBzAbmOQCMsPb7GRWhAL6EEAGzgY86KNhAAZYPQLsADphwZaMuXgC8KkiXJVaAcgAmEDAkaqwwHMiwwylEGYA07Elx7JLa1tge0cQZ1c-M3YhNnYmCDAdHAAKEDgAWwhaAGsIAE8XNA1cAEpDIyhEgFcocLAKJQA6dVlNAG10rIBdNhIREVFNMGRVMWQDEAgAd2K2hSUwFNK2BE0sMQgmsSwmFLGmhKSSlLMTD1KV5AB6a+QAdSwoHIwh3A2tnb2Do+SQU+wWRwEBAWAcIHE1SsFjMlxYNzuAFEoFAnkA).

**But**, if you prefer to keep it inline, you can by using `keyof PersonList['persons']` as the parameter type:

```
class PersonList {
  persons = {
    john: 'description of john',
    bob: 'description of bob'
  };

  getPerson(name: keyof PersonList['persons']) {
    return this.persons[name];
  }
}
```

[Live on the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdgGQJYQC7QG8AoaaAByVTRgF5CTToArFACzQC5oByAE3gjBEWMrizpoKAGbM2abgBoGpAEYoVXPgKEixE6dDUruDAL4BuIgwDm8XAmToAFGjABbeFwDW8AJ4GHKmw8AG1uCkdqbgBdAEp6RmhEOwBXRDRoXFYcADoIqggQ1w9oy1JTIgqiYHQ8chBoOjR4AHc4SnRg3CdYyxrqFBB4HJAUaycyEBzbew60J24Wdm5Y3ugAenXoAHUURC8IatrB4dHxyem7QOduVA90eDQUMTRQFP5eFbXN6ABRREQeyAA).

---

In a comment you've asked:

> is it possible to implement this in an abstract class? ... it would be awesome to implement the getter in the abstract class, but I haven't found a solution so far.

...with a link to this code template:

```
abstract class AbstractPersonList {
  protected abstract persons: { [name: string]: string };
}

class Persons extends AbstractPersonList {
  persons = {
    john: 'this is john',
  }
}

class MorePersons extends AbstractPersonList {
  persons = {
    bob: 'this is bob',
  }
}
```

You can parameterize `AbstractPersonList`:

```
abstract class AbstractPersonList<T extends {[name: string]: string}> {
// ------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  protected abstract persons: T;
  public getPerson(name: keyof T): string {
    return this.persons[name];
  }
}
```

Then you'd have:

```
class Persons extends AbstractPersonList<{john: string}> {
// -------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  persons = {
    john: 'this is john',
  }
}

class MorePersons extends AbstractPersonList<{bob: string}> {
// -----------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  persons = {
    bob: 'this is bob',
  }
}
```

Which leads to these results, which I think are what you're looking for:

```
let n = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'john' : 'bob';

const p = new Persons();
console.log(p.getPerson('john'));  // Works
console.log(p.getPerson('bob'));   // FAILS: Argument of type '"bob"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"john"'.
console.log(p.getPerson(n));       // FAILS: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"john"'.

const mp = new MorePersons();
console.log(mp.getPerson('john')); // FAILS: Argument of type '"john"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"bob"'.
console.log(mp.getPerson('bob'));  // Works
console.log(mp.getPerson(n));      // FAILS: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"bob"'.
```

[Live on the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgguacIAUBTKMAewDsAZAS0gB4AVBQgDwkPIBMMBvAbXLAAtoQBcCSFGrkA5gF1xk6TIC+APgQ8AUAgQAHKKXbxCnBKEl59xMuTDiGAbh36AriGTVYCGYQI2KAApBEXEAa0IAT1IAMwQGAEpFaGVNF10oP1cocgQIAAtaADo9ALsBYUI5Z10VLTqtFDQMIhIKDFZ2LgxsS3hW2xp6HgArUnzyZKlZdTTdUra7BABeOd0EMYnxAHIC2gR9zfJtgBoXOoam9AQAWVJMgfbmNg5uLBwYfrKhiDoeEFIICmylm2nmZQwqzB6wBQIQu0KGH2sNO53qWi0yD8CFyqxuwAKRRgXFIQkCCQQdAQAAYigBWBAAfnhR22CB2KOcjXaiD0KxxhAA7ghHnZyc5YO1SFiishSDJAnoir5-ItAttWQkEo4EAB6XUIADq9zCYG5dmlhFl8sVyr8ovVKK1Ov1CAAYsBqMgzZKLTK5QqlSqHeRnXqDR6vWbzZAEEI+atyELbvdCKKwOKY5brQr43bVbZ1ZrteH3Z7vVn-Ta88Gyo7Adsw67jVBTZWrQHAjX7XXQyXXZHvUA).

Comment: Sadly I mixed up type and value in the example. `persons` is not a type but a value (in the example a simple `[name: string]: string`, but way more complicated in the application I'm working on).

Comment: @nehalist - No worries and thanks for clarifying. I've updated the answer with two options for you.

Comment: Wouldn't `interface Persons {
  [key: string]: string;
}` make more sense as the definition...?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - The OP wants to avoid having keys that aren't `john` or `bob`, apparently, since they want `'someonenotincluded'` to cause an error.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that. Fair enough.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ahh, I've tried `keyof PersonList.persons` instead of `[]`. Thanks!

Comment: @nehalist - Happy to help! At least part of the credit goes to Titian Cernicova-Dragomir, who taught me this trick a little while back.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder One additional question: is it possible to implement this in an abstract class? See https://gist.github.com/nehalist/dd01964dffa2e396cd45abe8969899bc - it would be awesome to implement the getter in the abstract class, but I haven't found a solution so far.

Comment: @nehalist - I think you can do that if you parameterize `AbstractPersonList`, I've added to the end of the answer.